# fast way to convert datetime to string

Tags: string, matlab, datetime

I want to know if there is faster way to convert a datetime to a  string besides `datestr`.

datetime is inserted every other lines in my main function (including all of its dependency). I need time at that line of code is executed.

I think my only option is to convert datetime to string faster.

```
t = datetime('now');
DateString = datestr(t);
```

I profiled and it seems it is called 12570846 times. It takes 16030.021s in total.

My goal of doing this is get the current time when the line is executed and to match with other information that I get from other program with timestamps. I match two files (one from this MATLAB code and one from my other program) with time stamps.

Comment: Impossible to answer without knowing *how* you're calling `datestr` and what form your data is in. Are you sure it's `datestr` that is taking up the time? Have you profiled your code? What version of MATLAB are you using?

Comment: @excaza It is called 12570846 times in my main function. It takes 16030.021s in total. I am calling datestr as t = datetime('now'), and string = datestr(t).

Comment: Why call it in a loop at all? It's a vectorized function. Provide a **reproducible** example and edit it into your question, not in the comments...

Comment: Do you want to do profiling? Matlab has a tool for that, no need to put datetimes everywhere to see what takes time!!!

Comment: The edit still does not explain *why* you need to do this every other line and *why* you need to convert it to a string every other line...inside a loop. There are far better ways to profile your code. "Do I need to do this" and "how do I do this faster" are equally important questions.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Thank you for input. However I do need timestamp at each line of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way you could do this would be to compare the current time to the time the previous time through the loop. You should only recompute the `datestring` value if it's different. But we can actually go a step further, because the output of `datestr` (as you're calling it) only shows *seconds.* So we can actually ignore microsecond differences.

### Example Using `now` (~128 Seconds)

Below I have an example loop that caches the date string representation. It compares the serial date (in seconds) to the date for which the last date string was generated. Only if it's different is the date string updated.

```
% Number of seconds in a day to convert the serial date number
secperday = 60 * 60 * 24;

% Store the current time as a reference
lasttime = now;
datestring = datestr(lasttime);

for k = 1:12570846
    N = now;
    seconds = round(N * secperday);

    if ~isequal(lasttime, seconds)
    % Update the cache
        lasttime = seconds;
        datestring = datestr(N);
    end

    % Use datestring however you want
    disp(datestring)
end
```

### Example using `clock` (~24 seconds)

Another option is to use `clock` which will give you the different date components in a vector. You can round the last element which represents seconds and milliseconds. By rounding it you suppress the milliseconds. This method seems to be a faster approach.

```
N = clock;

% Remove milliseconds
N(end) = round(N(end));
lasttime = N;
datestring = datestr(N);

for k = 1:12570846
    N = clock;
    % Ignore milliseconds
    N(end) = round(N(end));

    if ~isequal(N, lasttime)
        lasttime = N;
        datestring = datestr(N);
    end

    disp(datestring)
end
```

### Funtion-Based Solution

If you want to get the current time as a date string at several points within your code, it is likely much better to create a function which will wrap this functionality. Here is an example of such a function.

```
function str = getDateString()
    % Use persistent variables to cache the current value
    persistent lasttime datestring

    % Get the current time
    thistime = clock;

    % Truncate the milliseconds
    thistime(end) = floor(thistime(end));

    % See if the time has changed since the last time we called this
    if ~isequal(thistime, lasttime)
        lasttime = thistime;

        % Update the cached string reprsentation
        datestring = datestr(thistime);
    end

    str = datestring;
end
```

You can then call this from anywhere within your code to get the date string and it will only be computed when necessary.

Comment: He shouldn't be calculating and displaying a string inside the loop at all. He's running this for *every single line of code, inside of a loop*. There's absolutely no way to effectively use 12 million strings, and any comparison should be done on the number anyway...

Comment: @excaza I agree. I'm not sure what's *actually* happening inside this loop and why a date is needed.

Comment: I would not assume that `datetime('now')` returns the serial date in seconds. The [output of `datetime` supports fractional seconds](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html#zmw57dd0e174493). Also, `datestr` does support milliseconds.

Comment: @excaza I don't. That's why I actually round the seconds component to get rid of the fractional component. Am I not doing that properly? In my tests it seems to work fine.

Comment: I didn't say it's incorrect, I just don't necessarily agree with the premise. Though since the OP is using the default output of `datestr` it's a wash anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If your loop time is pretty short you might convert the date time every 10th loop or something like that if it will be close enough.

Comment: Yes that might help. How can I do make one line runs only in every 10 iterations?

Comment: This should be a comment, since there is no code involved in which you show how to implement this.